# X11 font could not be loaded

Tags: r, x11, xvfb, x11-forwarding

This post is a continuation of a previous post by me: [Using R without X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277506/using-r-without-x11) and I tried to implement what was suggested to me. So my previous command was:

```
bsub -XF -n 1 -R "rusage[mem=16]" -We 60 -J <job_array> -o out.log 'script.pl <script arguments>'
```

I use `-XF` because of the reasons stated in my previous question. Without using `-XF` I get the following error:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
```

unable to start device PNG

Now, I tried to implement the suggestions given under my question. This is my new command without `-XF` and using `xvfb-run`.

```
bsub -n 1 -R "rusage[mem=16]" -We 60 -J <job_array> -o out.log 'xvfb-run script.pl <script arguments>'
```

So, technically if `xvfb-run` doesn't work, it should give me the same error as that without using `-XF`, but it gives me a different error:

```
Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : 
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 10 could not be loaded
```

I am unable to understand what is happening here. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!